# Blocking a section of text so that it is printed on one page

Tags: python, html, pandas, printing

My program generates some text and tables as HTML  report files. Tables may vary in length depending on the week. I want the text under the tables to be on one page, it cannot be split into two pages when printed out.

I don't have any idea how to do this, thanks for any help.

This is a sample of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
            
<head>      
   <title>Some title</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

Some style formating...

</style>
<body>

Some text......

{DF.to_html()}

Some text.....

{DF.to_html()}

Text that need to be on one page when printed
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are CSS properties like `page-break-*` than can hint page breaks, but when the text is too long it will always be split. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Comment: Provide a PDF of the same page to the end user